# How to import an npm module with ES6 in an Electron application

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, electron

I'm writing an Electron application using ES6 and **ChartJS**. I have babel fully set up and works fine. So far the only way I have gotten ChartJS to work is by sticking the (CDN) javascript into my head tag. When I try to import it the ES6 way (not sure how to do so properly), or simply using `var Chart = require('chartjs')` I get the error that `Chart` is not defined.

I installed ChartJS with
`npm install chartjs --save`

I have tried various ways of loading the javascript but they all end up blank. Only when I uncomment the CDN it works.

How do I import and use ChartJS in an electron app?

My structure

```
root_folder/
├── lib/
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── plot.js
│   ├── channel.js
├── src/
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── plot.js
│   ├── channel.js
├── index.html
└── main.js
```

At the bottom of my `index.html` I simply call `app.js` which is the entry point for the renderer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>

<script>
  require('./lib/app.js')
</script>

</html>
```

## Edit 1:

I've run some tests and even the most simple `var Chart = 
require('chartjs');` in a clean file automatically instantiates the chart as a `BarChart`. From what I've been reading is that it has to be imported globally somehow which is what happens when it's inside a `<script>` tag in the head.

Comment: Try using requirejs. http://requirejs.org/

Comment: It should be `var chart = require('chartjs')`, not `var chart = require(chartjs)`. Please, explain where exactly did you do that and what happened. Because this is how it's usually done.

Comment: @estus ah yes that was a slight typo. I put it in various locations: head tag, after body even in the single file where I use the `Chart` module (`plot.js`)

Answer (score 1):

[`chart.js` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chart.js) is loaded from CDN in head script.

[`chartjs` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs) is loaded in `require`.

They are different packages with different names.

Generally this should be done with

```
var Chart = require('chart.js');
```

in the place where a module should be used.

If the application is transpiled with Babel, ES module imports are translated to `require` in transpiled code, and `require` can be replaced with equivalent `import` statement:

```
import * as Chart from 'chart.js';
```

Answer (score -2):

> var chart = require(chartjs) I get the error that Chart is not
>   defined.

There's a few things here that need fixing. First you mentioned you were using ECMAScript 6 so change `var` to `const`. Also change `require` to ES6's `import`, and import the default package from `chart js` (looks like it may be just `chart`.

The other thing was already mentioned, you should be putting `chartjs` in quotes: `"chartjs"`.

In summation, it should look something like,

```
import chart from 'chartjs`
```

After you run this line, try logging `chart` and you should see the chart API

Comment: `import` won't work if this isn't transpiled code (and it's not).

Comment: @estus That is inaccurate. `import` is supported by Chrome 60 &61, Edge 38, Firefox 54, Safari 10.1, and Opera 47

Comment: I'm transpiling my application files as noted in the initial question. The quotes were my typo in the question. Let me try this

Comment: And Electron supports import too, because it has Chrome under the hood. But try to import NPM package with native `import` like that and you'll see what happens.

Comment: @estus I have used `import chart from 'chartjs'` However when I `console.log(chart)` I see it has created a `BarChart` object already instead of it being like this when I use the CDN `function (t,e){return this.construct(t,e),this}`

Comment: @Ortix92 beware of CDN's as they might be delivering older versions (and then you end up with obscure bugs). Can you paste what you see when you log `chart` ?

Comment: @SuaMorales node.js does not support modules (even the most current version) and electron is built partly on node. Nor do modlules work in Chrome 60 without a flag.